# How to pass a variable from a post request to a function that takes params as string or array of string in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, variables

I would like to pass the variable below called query into the end of the prompt , I tried template literals but it doesn't work

```
(async () => {
  const gbtResponse = await openai.createCompletion({
    model: "text-davinci-002",
    prompt:
      "Generate a product description explanation for the following product:  \n\n",
    temperature: 0.8,
    max_tokens: 256,
    top_p: 1,
    frequency_penalty: 0,
    presence_penalty: 0,
  });
  console.log(`${gbtResponse.data.choices[0].text}`);
  // console.log(`${gbtResponse}.choices[0].text`);
  app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
    res.send(`${gbtResponse.data.choices[0].text}`);
  });
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

  app.post("/api", (req, res) => {
    res.send(
      `I received your POST request. This is what you sent me: ${req.body.productName}`
    );
    const query = req.body.productName;
    console.log(`${query}`);
  });
})();
```

Comment: can you explain a little more what do you want to do with the `query` variable?

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa I want to be able to put it at the end of the prompt after the word product: 
"Generate a product description explanation for the following product: \n\n",

PS. I cant use template literals

Answer (score 0):

I think what you will need to do is this:

```
  const gbtResponse = async (param) => {
    return await openai.createCompletion({
    model: "text-davinci-002",
    prompt:
      `Generate a product description explanation for the 
      following product: ${param} \n\n`,
    temperature: 0.8,
    max_tokens: 256,
    top_p: 1,
    frequency_penalty: 0,
    presence_penalty: 0,
  });
}
```

and then rather than referring it you need to call it.

Since you specified you don't want to use template literals you could use this approach.

```
    prompt:
      "Generate a product description explanation for the 
      following product: " +  param + "\n\n",
```

Comment: I can't use template literals in prompt, it has to be a string

Comment: How does template literals effect anything? your function will still recieve a string. but a more jank way would be concat the string I'll mention it in the answer.

Comment: check the alternative solution out.

Comment: I just did this, It still says the API call failed

Comment: could you share the error ?